# Asyncio - RELIABLY Always Close Straggling TCP Connections

Tags: sockets, tcp, python-asyncio

I have a program which connects to a bunch of hosts and checks if they are "socket reflectors". Basically, it is scanning a bunch of ips and doing this:

*Connect, check - if there is data, is that data the same as what I am sending? Yes, return true, no return false. No data, return false.*

For some reason, asyncio is not reliably closing TCP connections after they time out. I attribute this to the fact that a lot of these hosts I am connecting to are god knows what, and maybe just buggy servers. Be that as it may, there must be a way to make this force timeout? When I run this, it hangs after a while. Out of 12,978 hosts, about 12,768 of them complete. Then I end up with a bunch of open ESTABLISHED connections! Why does this happen?

I need it close the connection if nothing happens during the given timeout period.

```
async def tcp_echo_client(message, host_port, loop, connection_timeout=10):
    """
    Asyncio TCP echo client
    :param message: data to send
    :param host_port: host and port to connect to
    :param loop: asyncio loop
    """

    host_port_ = host_port.split(':')
    try:
        host = host_port_[0]
        port = host_port_[1]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    else:

        fut = asyncio.open_connection(host, port, loop=loop)
        try:
            reader, writer = await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout=connection_timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('[t] Connection Timeout')
            return 1
        except Exception:
            return 1

        else:

            if args.verbosity >= 1:
                print('[~] Send: %r' % message)
            writer.write(message.encode())
            writer.drain()
            data = await reader.read(1024)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            if data:
                if args.verbosity >= 1:
                    print(f'[~] Host: {host} Received: %r' % data.decode())
                if data.decode() == message:
                    honeypots.append(host_port)
                    writer.close()
                    return 0
                else:
                    filtered_list.append(host_port)
                    print(f'[~] Received: {data.decode()}')
                    writer.close()
                    return 1
            else:
                filtered_list.append(host_port)
                writer.close()
                if args.verbosity > 1:
                    print(f'[~] No data received for {host}')
                    return 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see a timeout on your `read` call. You should have timeouts on all reads and writes. Also, your code should handle the situation where `read` returns a subset of the data you sent, buffering as necessary and calling additional `read`s until the complete message is read.

Comment: Okay - can you show me to implement a timeout on read properly?

Comment: I believe using an `asyncio.wait_for` wrapper should be sufficient. I'm not familiar with Python socket APIs, though.

Comment: Yes, you are correct